# Stata error i ambiguous abbreviation when trying to run a loop in

Tags: regression, stata

I'm trying to run a regression for the variables below by state to compare them, but I cannot get the loop to run. This is the coe I have so far

```
foreach i in statefip{
   reg lnwage female parent age fulltime educfin i
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as Stata is concerned, you have set up a loop over one item, the variable `statefip`.

Also, the macro you declared is called `i`. It's not illegal not to reference that in the loop, but if you did reference it, you would need to refer to it using this kind of syntax:

```
sysuse auto, clear
foreach i in mpg weight price {
    su `i'
}
```

Note the single quotation marks around the local macro name.

Since you didn't refer to the macro, Stata can only interpret your reference to `i` as a reference to a variable (or scalar), and it turns out that in your dataset the reference is ambiguous. So, that's the immediate error.

But there's a deeper problem. You're interpreting `in` as meaning that Stata will look inside the variable you mention and loop over its distinct values. That is not at all how to loop over the distinct values of any variable. `foreach` doesn't work that way.

It is easier to use `by:` here, so that something more like

```
bysort statefip : reg lnwage female parent age fulltime educfin
```

is more likely to work. But that is not necessarily ideal, depending on what you want to do with the results. But at this point I don't know what you want to do with the results, so I will stop there.

The FAQ [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/) may be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a loop variable you need to enclose it with a leading left quote and trailing single right quote:

```
foreach i in statefip {
   reg lnwage female parent age fulltime educfin `i'
}
```

However, it is unclear what `statefip` is as you do not use quote enclosures for local macros, `` `statefip' ``, or dollar sign `$` for global macros, `$statefip`. As used above, only *one* regression will be run in loop where you pass in `statefip` as last variable of regression call:

```
reg lnwage female parent age fulltime educfin statefip
```

If `statefip` is a variable in the dataset and you want to run iterations off each unique value, then you need to iterate off its levels and filter data with `if` in the regression call. Below runs separate regressions for each unique value contained in `statefip` variable.

```
levelsof statefip, local(fips)

foreach f in `fips' {
   display "************ `f' ***********"
   reg lnwage female parent age fulltime educfin if statefip == "`f'"
}
```

Comment: `levelsof` could be a solution here (I've nothing against it; I'm the original author), but there are other solutions too. Also, you know this, but the OP needs to know that your solution assumes that `statefip` is a string variable, and it could be numeric.

Comment: All good points, Mr. Stata Guru! After seeing your `bysort` suggestion. I did a facepalm!